# Some gpx layers not loading in QField

Tags: qgis, qfield

I have a QGIS project that works fine loading all layers in the QGIS app on my tablet. If I create a QField project and export to QField on my tablet some layers do not load.
Inspecting a (gpx) layer that loads ok, the QGIS propertiies states the Provider as ogr, and the Identification Type is dataset. Layers that do not load state the provider as gpx, and do not have an Identification Type. I am using QGIS 3.22.4

How does this come about, and how is it fixed without upsetting the QGIS function on my tablet?

Comment: Turns out that this can be fixed by selecting an offending layer, choose 'Change Data Source', select Project Home, open file and click Track or Waypoint